# How to properly click a button on a site?

Tags: python, css, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to parse through a web-page using selenium and python and I need to click a button in the end of the page to load more links.

I tried doing this via find_element_by_css_selector, however this didn't work. I also tried find_elements_by_xpath, however i ran into a problem as well

```py
br.get('https://ru.armeniasputnik.am/economy/')
button=br.find_element_by_css_selector('.m-more')
button.click()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-efe3bd0e09ab> in <module>
      1 br.get('https://ru.armeniasputnik.am/economy/')
      2 button=br.find_element_by_css_selector('.m-more')
----> 3 button.click()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/economy/?id=19596655&amp;date=20190713T183900" data-href="/economy/more.html?id=19596655&amp;date=20190713T183900" data-for="rubric-major" class="b-btn m-more">...</a> is not clickable at point (449, 692). Other element would receive the click: <div class="global-fade globalFade" style="display: block;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.1 x86_64)

br.get('https://ru.armeniasputnik.am/economy/')
python_button = br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(concat(@class), concat("m-more"))]")[0]
python_button.click()

  File "<ipython-input-56-81bfa73ca6e5>", line 2
    python_button = br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(concat(@class), concat("m-more"))]")[0]
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect this code to load additional links.

Comment: If possible, share the relevant html code. So that its easier to provide a efficient solution.

Comment: The error clearly says that the xpath syntax is incorrect. Also, the use of contact method is incorrect.

The XPath-concat method works similar to the String#concat method. It joins two or more strings into a single string. The argument strings maybe two or more static strings and/or they may be two or more XPathExpression to evaluate. The output from the XPathExpressionis then concatenated and the resulting string is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use either `Action Class` or  `JavaScripts Executor` to click on the button.

Using `JavaScripts Executor`

```
button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.m-more')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)
```

Using `Action Class`

```
button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.m-more')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

For Action class you need to imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you cannot click the button due to modal popup which doesn't allow anything else to be clicked:

[image]

So I would recommend to:

1. [Wait until "More" button is present](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)
2. [Check if it is clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled)
3. [If it is not clickable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) - assume that the modal popup is present, close the popup
4. [Click](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) "More" button

Example code:

```
more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'m-more')]")))
if not more.is_enabled():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'modalClose')]").click()
more.click()
```